# Zend framework how to get params from url

Tags: php, zend-framework

My url is as below

```
domain.com/admin/delete/1/2/3
```

I want to get last value 1 2 and 3 in different variable.

may be like segment

```
delete($arg1,$arg2,$arg3){  }
```

OR

```
$param = getallparam();
```

Please any one let me know how can I achieve this in zend framework.
My zf version is 1.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it in this way
Update your url as

```
domain.com/admin/delete/str1/1/str2/2/str3/3
```

now use code

```
echo "<pre>";
     print_r($this->_request->getParams());
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is custom routing. When you initialize the application, you can add something like the following to your FrontController:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->setParam('useDefaultControllerAlways', false);
$front->setControllerDirectory('application/controllers');

$front->getRouter()->addRoute('mycontrol', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/action/:param1/:param2/:param3', array(
                    'controller' => 'mycontrol', 
                    'module' => 'default',
                    'action' => 'action',
                    'param1' => ''),
                    'param2' => ''),
                    'param3' => ''))
);
```

Then, in your controller (i.e. in MycontrolController->actionAction()) you can access the parameters as

```
$param1 = $this->_request->getParam('param1', $default = '');
$param2 = $this->_request->getParam('param2', $default = '');
$param3 = $this->_request->getParam('param3', $default = '');
```